# .html() not filling div on page change back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a page with this page init event function

```
$("#myPage").live('pageinit', function () 
{
    // here is some irrelevant parsing code

    console.log("myHTMLStr: "+myHTMLStr);
    $('#result_content').html(myHTMLStr);
}
```

and this div: `<div id="result_content"></div>`

The console.log result is always the same, no matter how I get to the page. But, when I get to the page from the previous one (through something like `$.mobile.changePage(MyPage, { transition: 'none', reverse: false });`, the `result_content` div is filled with the content of `myHTMLStr`. But when I get there from the next screen, using the back button, which is implemented like this:

```
<a data-role="button" href="MyPage.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left"
   class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="none">
    MyPage
</a>
```

The div element `result_content` is not filled. Is it possible that the `.html()` function is not working? what else could be happening??

**UPDATE**

I am using jquery-1.8.2 with jquery.mobile-1.3.0. Testing on Android (Samsung Galaxy SII)

Comment: `pageinit` fires once, use `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: @Omar it really isn't an issue with the calling of the function. `console.log("myHTMLStr: "+myHTMLStr);`is called when it should and even has the correct content.

Comment: `.html()` is likely working, and should be called as well since `console.log()` is called. I would guess it has to do with how the page is loaded. Have you actually confirmed that `$('#result_content')` actually grabs the element?

Comment: what type of items you want to append? can you share the code?

Comment: @Zhihao it passes over the same code when it is loaded correctly, so it should be grabbing the element.

Comment: As discussed in my now deleted answer, can you/you can state in your OP that you are using a .live() supporting version of jQuery.

Comment: are you using `id=result_content` in other pages?

Comment: @Omar YES! the next page had the same element, because it still was like a copy of the previous (placeholder). It seems that it was grabbing the element from the wrong site. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: you can use `$.mobile.activePage.find('#result_content').html('foo')` if you still want to use same id. But its not recommended at all in jQM

Comment: Thank you @Omar. I didn't need to use the same id. Please post your previous comment as an answer, so I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't working because of duplicate `id`s' in DOM. Use unique `id` for elements whether you are using *Single-Page Template* or *Multi-Page Template*.

Reference: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id